# Should we use Koin Inject inside an Adapter? Or should we try to put this responsibility to the Activity/Fragment and its ViewModels?

Tags: android, adapter, viewmodel, inject, koin

Is it a good practice to do the following code?

Or should I remove these injected objects and try to handle all the things related to this adapter in its parent's ViewModel (creating a Listener between the adapter and its parent activity/fragment)?

```kotlin
class MyAdapter(private val listener: Listener) :
    ListAdapter<MyEntity, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ItemDiffCallback()) {

    // Getting instances using Koin Dependency Injection
    private val dispatchers: CoroutineContextProvider
        by inject(CoroutineContextProvider::class.java)

    private val roomRepository: roomRepository
        by inject(roomRepository::class.java)

    ...
}
```

Comment: "Is it a good practice to do the following code" - not particularily, this class now knows about how `dispatchers` and `roomRespository` should be provided (using koin delegate).  Prefer IoC and DI through the constructor. If you want to use this class without koin, currently you'd have to modify the class in order to decouple it from koin.

Comment: @MarkKeen excellent point! So, I think that a good way is to put this adapter in the list of modules started by Koin, passing `dispatchers` and `roomRepository` in the constructor. Now, the parent of the adapter will have `myAdapter: MyAdapter by inject()`. Right?